# Unable to replace String containing special characters "["

Tags: groovy, jmeter, replaceall

My groovy version is 3.0.7.

I tried this:

```
String str1="Hello[World[Test"
String str2=str1.replaceAll("\\[","")
```

Error details:

```
2021-04-06 01:11:33,087 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script106.groovy: 19: Unexpected input: '(' @ line 19, column 24.
String str2 = str1.replaceAll("\[","")
```

how can I achieve this?

```
String str2=str1.replaceAll("\\[","")
```

Comment: I can not reproduce this with 3.0.7, saving the two lines into a file and running that with `groovy so.groovy`. The JSR223 stuff would suggest, that you are not just using groovy to run the code. Please provide all the facts that lead to that error.

Comment: Your source code shows `str1.replaceAll("\\[","")` which I think is valid but the error message shows  `str1.replaceAll("\[","")` which I think is not.  Is this code being entered in some context where the `\\` being evaluated before this code makes its way into a Groovy interpreter?

Comment: This code is part of jmeter JSR223 PostProcessor. With normal groovy script am able to replace the special character "[" with the replaceAll function. But same code is getting evaluated differently when it used with JSR223 PostProcessor. I need to replace "[" character in my result. How can I achieve this with JSR223 PostProcessor?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `replaceAll` method that `String` provides.

```
groovy:000> str1="Hello[World[Test"
===> Hello[World[Test
groovy:000> str1.replaceAll('\\[', '')
===> HelloWorldTest
```

```
~ $ groovy -version
Groovy Version: 2.5.13 JVM: 1.8.0_202 Vendor: Azul Systems, Inc. OS: Mac OS X
~ $ 
~ $ cat doit.groovy 
String str1='Hello[World[Test'
String str2 = str1.replaceAll('\\[', '')
println str2
~ $ 
~ $ groovy doit
HelloWorldTest
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem using latest [JMeter 5.4.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-4-1-released-td5739226.html) which comes with [Groovy 3.0.7](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/gradle.properties#L86)

[image]

The problem is not with these 2 lines, it's somewhere else, just before these lines or right after them, it's hard to tell where exactly without seeing the full Post-Processor script.

Also if this is the only thing your code is doing you might want to consider using [__strReplace()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup) or [__strReplaceRegex()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplaceRegexsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup) instead, they are [Custom JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-custom-jmeter-functions-plugin) which can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]

Comment: For me, same is working with JSR 223 sampler but the issue is with JSR223 PostProcessor whereas am getting the error ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script106.groovy: 19: Unexpected input: '(' @ line 19, column 24. String str2 = str1.replaceAll("[","") –

Comment: "The same" will work no matter in which JSR223 test element "the same" is called, if you create a new test plan with a [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) or a [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide/) add the JSR223 PostProcessor with "the same" code you should see "the same" result for "the same".